# different folders within Xcode c++ project

Tags: c++, xcode

When I create a Xcode project for c++ modules , it creates a folder within the top folder and has the same name .

for example if I create a new project and name it data structures (this has the .xcodeproj file), it creates another folder data structures within this, which has the actual file.

what i want is that its just the top data structures folder and then within this i create different folders like trees, graphs etc as and when required.

Currently if i rename the internal data structures folder, my files don't run .

How can I achieve this ?.

Comment: What sorts of error messages are you seeing when you rename the internal data structures folder?

Comment: When i click build it doesn't compile the new file i edited, it recompiles the old one. Also if i create a new file it goes in the top level data structures folder and not the sub folder I intend it to be in.   I still don't understand why it creates a subfolder with the same name . I have data structures->data structures, .xcodeproj -> my files.    I know its a basic question but  I'm new to Xcode and this project organization isn't really intuitive ..